# How can I further query the result of an Esri REST endpoint query in JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am querying Esri REST endpoint to get features from a dataset, but how can I further query the resultset that comes back without making a call back out to the server?

I make an initial js call very broad so that I get all of the features I could possibly need. Then on that data set, in JavaScript, I want to make a sub query

Do I use Esri syntax against the local dataset somehow? 
Or is there a JavaScript query language? 
Or do I blindly loop over the dataset?

Comment: Once you've made a request to ArcGIS Server, you have a JSON object containing the matching features. If you wish to sub-set those features without a further query to the server, you'll probably need to write a function to iterate through all of the results, and keep the features that you wish to retain while ignoring the others.

Answer (score 1):

You can further filter your collection of feature results using JavaScript. Suppose you want to filter the features based on an field called TYPE. Use the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method like so:

```
filteredFeatures = features.filter(function(x) { return x.attributes['TYPE'] == '2';});
```

Comment: that was what i wound up doing James, thanks for the tip. seems that the esri query task should just take a local dataset instead of a rest endpoint if you have it already.